# How do run set command with memcached via netcat/telnet

Tags: memcached

I'm trying to understand memcached and troubleshoot one of my applications that uses it, but I'm having a hard time executing the `set` command. I'm following this tutorial here. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/memcached/memcached_set_data.htm Here is what I'm trying.

```
nc localhost 11211
set tutorialspoint 0 900 9
memcached

CLIENT_ERROR bad data chunk
```

I've looked at a couple of other tutorials and I've even looked at the source code of a Golang client and they all seem to be calling `set` like this, but for some reason it's not working for me.

I'm on an arm MacBook running memcached version 1.6.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at some memcached clients and the memcached source code, I found that memcached is looking for the `\r\n` line endings and Mac only uses the line feed (LF or \n).

To solve the problem with netcat, I followed this answer here. https://superuser.com/questions/942217/how-do-i-interactively-type-r-n-terminated-query-in-netcat. It says you can use the `-C` option but that didn't work for me, and I had to type `control-v` + `control-m` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`membash` memcached bash client in github.

- https://gist.github.com/goodevilgenius/11375877

All you need commands are there.